# Android studio gradle too long

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image]

my android studio build too time ,i print the log is show app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac   has take my 37s , i build the project it take 53s ,too long to wait ...

Comment: What exactly is the question here? You only made a statement

Comment: How to reduce compilation time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are Gradle build tasks. Gradle is the build automation system of Android Studio and it has set of tasks to perform in order to build apk. Each time you run/build project it goes through these list of tasks one after another. Build time depends on your project code and dependencies you used in your project.

**Gradle Build Life Cycle**

Gradle is a language for dependency based programming. In Gradle terms this means that you can define tasks and dependencies between tasks. Gradle guarantees that these tasks are executed in the order of their dependencies, and that each task is executed only once. These tasks form a Directed Acyclic Graph. There are build tools that build up such a dependency graph as they execute their tasks. Gradle builds the complete dependency graph before any task is executed.

It is the Gradle build life cycle. It has three phases

*) Initialization

*) Configuration

*) Execution

[Official Document ion On Build LifeCycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

You may try to add the following code to your **gradle.properties** file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx5124m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

This may help speed up your gradle build.